# Is it possible to run a module written for drupal 7 in drupal 6?

Tags: 6

In another question I was searching for a module that provides a simple shopping cart and checkout process ([Is there a simple shopping cart and checkout process module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109320/is-there-a-simple-shopping-cart-and-checkout-process-module)).

I have found this simple module called [Basic Card](https://drupal.org/project/basic_cart).

I am running Drupal 6.x while this module is written only for Drupal 7.x.

Is it possible to run a Drupal 7.x module on a Drupal 6.x installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not generally possible without back-porting the code.

The API is very different between Drupal 6 and 7. A few things have remained the same, so it's theoretically possible that a module for one version might work as-is in the other version, but generally speaking, it's not possible.

For a proper idea of the task ahead of you, take a look at [Converting 6.x modules to 7.x](https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7). Not a trivial task, unfortunately.

I just had a quick look and the specific module you've mentioned definitely won't work in Drupal 6, it would need to be re-written.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

The APIs has changed, and this means that a lot of function calls is generate errors that will make your site useless.

A slightly longer answer is "maybe, if you're willing to do some work".

Many Drupal 7 modules doesn't use critical functions that *only* exists in Drupal 7.  This means that you can "downgrade" them from Drupal 7 to Drupal 6 by rewriting the hooks and other functions that calls the Drupal API to conform to Drupal 6.  I've done it myself with a couple of modules, and if you're familiar with both sets of APIs, it usually doable.